# Reference view in another layout

Tags: android

Is this possible? I have 2 activities and 2 layouts, but I want to reference a view which belongs to another .xml and not the one being inflated by the current activity. How do I do this?

```
private ChildEventListener pendingListener;
private ChildEventListener matchesListener;
private ChildEventListener alertListener;
private ValueEventListener flightListener;
private ValueEventListener prefsListener;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

    bLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogout);

    bLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            logout();
        }
    });

}

    private void logout(){
    if(pendingListener != null){
        System.out.println(TAG +" pending listener removed");
        mFirebaseRef
                .child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_USERS)
                .child(CURRENT_USER.getId())
                .child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_PENDING).removeEventListener(pendingListener);
    }

    if(matchesListener != null){
        System.out.println(TAG +" accept listener removed");
        mFirebaseRef
                .child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_USERS)
                .child(CURRENT_USER.getId())
                .child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_MATCHES).removeEventListener(matchesListener);
    }

    if(flightListener != null){
        System.out.println(TAG + " flight listener removed");
        mFirebaseRef
                .child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_FLIGHTS)
                .child(CURRENT_USER.getId()).removeEventListener(flightListener);
    }

    if(alertListener != null){
        System.out.println(TAG + " alert listener removed");
        mFirebaseRef.child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_USERS)
                .child(CURRENT_USER.getId())
                .child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_ALERTS).removeEventListener(alertListener);
    }

    if(prefsListener != null){
        System.out.println(TAG + " prefsListener removed");
        mFirebaseRef.child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_USERS)
                .child(CURRENT_USER.getId())
                .child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_PREFS).removeEventListener(prefsListener);
    }

    if(this.mAuthData != null){
        mFirebaseRef.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
        System.out.println(TAG + " authState listener removed");
    }

    // After logout, go to main activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainScreen.this, loginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The app crashes at .setOnClickListener. bLogout's id is defined in another layout, not main_screen

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem. Please show in code what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Why don't you set it in the other activity?

Comment: Because logout() closes a bunch of listeners which are defined in MainScreen, unless I make them static. I figured this approach would be more feasible as having a bunch of variables set to static is bad practice (or am i wrong?)

Comment: Why don't you broadcast the logout to close those listeners?

Comment: Broadcast? I'm unfamiliar with that concept. I'm still a novice when it comes to android development

Comment: Or use a handler to send data between the activity 2 to the activity 1? Because I assume that you don't want to use onActivityResult.

Comment: Can you provide the code of the `logout()` method ? I don't really see what kind of listeners you're talking about. Whatever it is, if they live outside the `MainScreen` activity, you should be able to access them from the other activity where `bLogout` is defined.

Comment: Open a new question and send me the link and I'll attach there the answer.

Comment: Or edit this one to ask about broadcasting

Answer (score 0):

> How to call Activity1 logout() function from Activity2

Create a Broadcast Receiver which call logout():

```
public class YourBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //local variables
    private Context mContext;

    public YourBroadcastReceiver(Context mContext){

        this.mContext = mContext;
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals("LOGOUT")) {

            ((YourActivity) mContext).logout();

        }
    }

}
```

Register BroadcastReceiver in Activity 1:

```
public mYourBroadcastReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //........
    //Create an Intent Filter
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("LOGOUT");
    mYourBroadcastReceiver = new YourBroadcastReceiver(this);
    //Register receiver
    registerReceiver(mYourBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    //.........
}
    @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (EcologDriverAIDApplication.DEBUG) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");

    }
    //Unregister receiver before destroy activity
    unregisterReceiver(mYourBroadcastReceiver);
    mYourBroadcastReceiver = null;
}
```

Broadcast logout:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent("LOGOUT");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Hope helps

Answer (score 0):

Upon further research, this was simply solved by making logout public and writing the following for the onClickListener for bLogout in my fragment

```
        //call logout in MainScreen
    ((MainScreen)getActivity()).logout();
```